# background url--image path

Tags: html, css, django, image, path

i am writing a project in django.
i have a css code:

```
  .featurette1 {
  height: 62px
  width:1030px;
  margin: 100px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
  background-image: url("${ STATIC_URL }base_app/images/apple.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I was orignally in my base_template.htm(include between style tags and it worked perfectly fine. But after I move it to base_template.css. the image can not be read.  I think I need to change the image path?

my image path is : projectname/base_app
Here is all my imports:

at top

```
    <%! from base_app import static_files %>
    <%  static_renderer = static_files.StaticRenderer(self) %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/base_app/styles/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/base_app/styles/base_template.css"/>
```

at bottom

```
${ static_renderer.get_template_js(request, context)  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to include `${ STATIC_URL }` in your image URL.
According to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri), the path in `url()` are relative to the stylesheet.

You could probably use something like:

```
.featurette1 {
  height: 62px
  width:1030px;
  margin: 100px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
  background-image: url("../images/apple.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you. Actually i tried this before BUT I forgot to pus "". Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted to improve readability (and my rep ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check your project's settings.py and add this:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/path/to/project/static/',
)
```

Then in your template(.html file) try adding:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "base_app/styles/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also in your css you don't need to use `STATIC_URL` just try:

```
background-image: url("base_app/images/apple.png");
```

Finally I think the tutorial on the django website would help you a lot! Have a look at it!

Comment: Is that really bad to include css code in html pages using style tags?it is a more professional way to put all css codes into a css file? I may just my code in my html page.

Comment: i changed the setting. nothing happened

Comment: Well it's better to keep them separate. In the future you will end up with thousands lines of code(imagine css + html in one file). Also when you use an .css file you can use its classes in many templates.
**Update** I edited my answer. So you may wanna try it again. Hope it helps!